# Bash Script Loop Through MySQL

Tags: mysql, bash, loops

I need a bash script that can retrieve MySQL data from a remote data base. Actually I have that done, but what I need it to do now is loop through the records somehow and pass a variable to another bash file.
Here's my MySQL call:

```
mysql -X -u $MyUSER -p$MyPASS -h$MyHOST -D$MyDB -e'SELECT `theme_name`, `guid` FROM `themes` WHERE `theme_purchased`="1" AND `theme_compiled`='0';' > themes.xml
download_themes.sh
```

It exports the data into an xml file called theme.xml right now, I was just trying to figure out some way to loop through the data. I am trying to avoid PHP and perl and just trying to use bash. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there some specific reason you want to avoid scripting languages? You won't be able to parse xml properly in bash. You might even have problems unescaping the output. Why not go the easy way and use php / perl / python / lua / java / tcl / javascript / ... or seriously anything apart from bash which simply won't be able to do this properly for many outputs?

Comment: You don't know if there is a way to output as an array and loop through that? I've Googled this can I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

something like:

```
mysql -e "SELECT `theme_name`, `guid` FROM `themes` WHERE `theme_purchased`='1' AND `theme_compiled`='0'" | while read theme_name guid; do
    # use $theme_name and $guid variables
    echo "theme: $theme_name, guid: $guid"
done
```

in short: the `mysql` command outputs record separated by '\n' and fields separated by '\t' when the output is a pipe.  the `read` command reads a line, splits in fields, and puts each on a variable.

if your data has spaces in the fields, you get some problems with the default `read` splitting.  there are some ways around it; but if you're only reading two fields and one of them shouldn't have any spaces (like the `guid`), then you can put the 'dangerous' field at the end, and `read` will put everything 'extra' in the last variable.

like this:

```
mysql -e "SELECT `guid` `theme_name`, FROM `themes` WHERE `theme_purchased`='1' AND `theme_compiled`='0'" | while read guid theme_name; do
    # use $theme_name and $guid variables
    echo "theme: $theme_name, guid: $guid"
done
```

Comment: It seemed to have worked the first time, but now it gives me this:
/winterboard_theme_builder/get_themes.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
/winterboard_theme_builder/get_themes.sh: line 9: `done'

Comment: Actually the do was on the wrong line, but then I get a different error. It says /winterboard_theme_builder/get_themes.sh: line 7: read: `theme_name,': not a valid identifier

Comment: oh, right.  no commas between `read` arguments, and a semicolon before `do`. fixed

Comment: I have a problem with this approach. When you have in your loop results when the column cell have 2 word , then the command assign part of first variable to 1 and other part to 2 . Let's say if $theme_name="Theme Name" and $guid="12" in db then this command will echo theme:Theme guid:Name 12 . Any clue how to solve that????  
theme: LalaPala, guid: 44.5,40.18,44.52,40.17
theme: San, guid: Francisco   -122.58,37.81,-122.33,37.71
theme: Edirne, guid:   26.51,41.69,26.64,41.64

Comment: as I said in the answer, if only one of the columns can have spaces on it, just put it at the end.  the `read` command assigns all 'remaining' results to the last variable.  For anything more complex, you could in theory get it working with the exact amount of quoting; but better to use real encodings (XML, CSV, record-style, etc), or any other language that doesn't try to parse every string you handle.

Comment: You won't be able to set global variables inside that loop

Comment: Add `--skip-column-names` (`-N` for short) to skip the headers.  In this answer, the column names get processed as if they are data.

Answer (score 9):

Rather than outputting XML, may I suggest you simply use the `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` syntax or `mysql --batch --raw` to output tab-separated values.  You then have much easier access through bash to the rest of the Unix toolchain, like `cut` and `awk` to retrieve the fields you need and reuse them with Bash. No other scripting language is necessary and you needn't mess with XML.

```
mysql --batch --raw -u $MyUSER -p$MyPASS -h$MyHOST -D$MyDB -e'SELECT `theme_name`, `guid` FROM `themes` WHERE `theme_purchased`="1" AND `theme_compiled`='0';' \
| awk '{print "theme: " $1  " guid: " $2}'
```

Comment: Love this solution, it should be the accepted answer imho. Much cleaner, no loop, let's me easily configure my output with `awk print`. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer does not work when spaces are in the output. It is an easy fix (IFS=$'\t' -- Note the $ -- it is weird):

```
>mysql ... -BNr -e "SELECT 'funny man', 'wonderful' UNION SELECT 'no_space', 'I love spaces';" | while IFS=$'\t' read theme_name guid; do echo "theme: $theme_name guid: $guid"; done
theme: funny man guid: wonderful
theme: no_space guid: I love spaces
```

You will, of course, want to substitute your own query.

Answer (score 2):

Pipe '|' to while is dangerous, for the changes inside the loop happen in another subprocess and would not take effect in the current script.

By the way, I hate to turn to the external file solution.

I suggest to use "[Process Substitute](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html#PROCESSSUBREF)".

```
while read field1 field2 field3
do
done < <(mysql -NB -e "$sql")
#     ^
#   space needed
```

Comment: how to detect if the mysql query/connection fails, in this case?