# How to make script to execute sql query every 3 seconds for indefinite time UBUNTU 18.04

Tags: php, sql, loops, execute

I want to write php script to execute sql query every 3 seconds automatically and indefinitely until I stop it. 
this is my sql query that I want to execute

```
UPDATE users SET bouquet =
  '["12","10","11","8","9","6","7","5","4","3","2","1"]'
```

The database name is xtream_iptvpro

Sorry, I am a beginner so I really don't know any thing. Thanks for your help

Comment: "... execute sql query automatically and indefinitely until I stop it" -- What does this mean? Do you want to execute it periodically? How often?

Comment: Yes sorry, I need the query to be executed every 3 seconds

Comment: Instead of "patching" a column of a table, I would suggest you create a pre-insert/pre-update trigger. That way any new/updated row will have the "good" data right away.

Comment: How can I do that, I have no idea. I am still a beginner. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

you have to use any cli or a some other technology to proceed.

for example if it's mysql you can use PHP, java or you can build it using console command.

```
while true; do echo -n "execute your query here"; sleep 3; done

while true; do mysql -u root -p somedb -e "select * from mytable"; sleep 3; done
```

[This solultion might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918436/bash-script-loop-through-mysql)

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to store any output, I just need the query to be executed. Thanks for your help

Comment: well you can execute any query it's all up to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you periodically "patch" some column of a table, then the columns will have the wrong data for some time. You probably don't want that.

Instead, I think a trigger will be better, since it will "fix" the data on the fly while being inserted/updated. The table won't ever have the wrong data to begin with.

See [24.3.1 Trigger Syntax and Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html).

For example (tweak as necessary):

```
create table users (id int, bouquet varchar(100));

create trigger fix_data before insert on users 
for each row 
begin
  set NEW.bouquet = '["12","10","11","8","9","6","7","5","4","3","2","1"]';
end;
```

Then, if you run the following `INSERT` statements:

```
insert into users (id, bouquet) values (1, 'Hello');
insert into users (id) values (2);
insert into users (id, bouquet) values (3, null);
insert into users (id, bouquet) values (4,
  '["12","10","11","8","9","6","7","5","4","3","2","1"]');

select * from users;
```

You get the result:

```
id  bouquet                                           
--  ----------------------------------------------------
1   ["12","10","11","8","9","6","7","5","4","3","2","1"]
2   ["12","10","11","8","9","6","7","5","4","3","2","1"]
3   ["12","10","11","8","9","6","7","5","4","3","2","1"]
4   ["12","10","11","8","9","6","7","5","4","3","2","1"]
```

Comment: Okay so based on my understanding, I just execute this command in mysql and it will edit any new entry. I use phpmyadmin for my sql databases.

Comment: it keeps giving me error from line 4 SQL query:


create trigger fix_data before insert on users 
for each row 
begin
  set NEW.bouquet = '["12","10","11","8","9","6","7","5","4","3","2","1"]'
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: I don't know phpmyadmin, but you may need to change the SQL delimiter. By default is usually a semi-colon in most tools. That doesn't work for triggers, functions, and/or stored procedures.