# Finding rows with invalid regular expressions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table with a column that contains a regular expression used to match rows from other tables.
I then need to query like this

```
SELECT st.id
FROM some_table st
WHERE '1234' REGEXP st.regexp;
```

As long as the column regexp contains a valid expression or null the query will run fine.
But, if you have an invalid regexp in any of the rows, the entire query fails with error 3685.
It is then virtually impossible to find where the error is, as there is no function for validating the regular expression.
Something like VALID_REGEXP() would solve it like

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table st
WHERE NOT VALID_REGEXP(st.regexp);
```

I am validating on INSERT/UPDATE by doing

```
SELECT '' REGEXP 'regexp-to-test'
```

But, if an invalid expression find its way in anyway, there is no way to find it in several millions of rows, as you will have to test them one-by-one and looking for error 3685.

Any hint on how to, in one query, find all rows with invalid regular expressions in their regexp column?

```
SELECT '' REGEXP <expression>
```

will let me know if  is valid, as it will return a row while it will return with error 3685 if it fails.
But, testing row-by-row is not an options as there is a huge amount of rows to test.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because MySQL doesn't have a built-in Regex validator function you'll need to use something like a shell-script to test and report all regex patterns in your table - **but** after you do that you can prevent this happening in future by adding a `CHECK` constraint that runs the stored regex pattern against a known match (or known non-match) stored in the same row: if it's an invalid regex then the `CHECK` constraint will fail, thus preventing invalid patterns from being stored in the table in future.

### Part 1: Validate patterns in the shell:

[Using this QA as a source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918436/bash-script-loop-through-mysql), and [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147884/shell-variable-in-a-grep-regex).

```bash
mysql -e "SELECT pattern FROM my_patterns" | while read pattern; do
    
    echo "foobar" | grep "^${pattern}"

done
```

You'll need to update the data manually based on how each `grep` goes.

### Part 2: Prevent invalid patterns from being stored with a `CHECK` constraint:

For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_patterns (
  patId   int          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  pattern varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  test    varchar(50)  NOT NULL,
  
  CONSTRAINT PK_patterns PRIMARY KEY ( patId ),
  
  CONSTRAINT CK_pattern_test CHECK ( REGEXP_LIKE( test, pattern ) = 1 )
);

INSERT INTO my_patterns ( pattern, test ) VALUES ( '\\d\\d\\d', '123' ); -- OK

INSERT INTO my_patterns ( pattern, test ) VALUES ( '\\d\\w\\d', '1a3' ); -- OK

INSERT INTO my_patterns ( pattern, test ) VALUES ( '][', 'aaa' ); -- fails due to invalid pattern
```

> **Schema Error**: Check constraint '`CK_pattern_test`' is violated.

[Live example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f3byDB39nrVzja6ffU8ZMT/0).

Comment: Thanks. Part 2 solves the problem.
The project isn't live yet, so with this CHECK on DB level I will not risk getting corrupt data in, and then there will be no need query to find invalid expressions.